# Using menhir with sedlex

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexer, menhir

I need to use menhir with sedlex for whatever reason (utf-8), but don't know how to make the generated parser depend on `Sedlexing` instead of `Lexing`. Any tips?

When I run

```
menhir --infer parser.mly
```

the generated program has lines with `Lexing...`. I could change it manually, but there must be another way, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The parser.ml that is generated *should* have references to Lexing. Sedlexing is used to create the `lexbuf` that you send in to the parser, but the parser doesn't care if that lexbuf was created by Lexing or Sedlexing, as long as it can use functions like `Lexing.lex_start_p` and `Lexing.lex_curr_p` on it.

---

I used something like

```
ocamlbuild -use-menhir -tag thread -use-ocamlfind -quiet -pkg menhirLib \
  -pkg sedlex test.native
```

where test.ml uses parser.mly via calls to Parser.

---

For completeness, the command that's run by ocamlbuild is:

```
menhir --ocamlc 'ocamlfind ocamlc -thread -package sedlex -package menhirLib' \
  --explain --infer parser.mly
```

See a full example at https://github.com/unhammer/ocaml_cg_streamparse
(branch https://github.com/unhammer/ocaml_cg_streamparse/tree/match-singlechar-example shows a rule that matches a single code point like `a` or `ß` but not `aa`).

Comment: Tried running your last command (I don't use ocamlbuild), but the resulting `parser.ml` still depends on `Lexing`...